# mongorestore command | --db --nsInclude flags are deprecated

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

i am trying to start a mongorestore from a dump that i have with the command :

```
mongorestore --uri="<MY_URI>" --nsFrom "<DB>" --nsTo "<DB>" --gzip  --archive="<FILE>.tar.gz"
```

i get

```
2022-10-18T15:03:03.451+0300    The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
2022-10-18T15:03:03.486+0300    preparing collections to restore from
2022-10-18T15:03:06.693+0300    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: Did you specify the database name in `MY_URI`?

Comment: yes i did

username:pass@IP/DB

Comment: Try to skip the DB name

Comment: after a long research it seems that the process is related to the way that mongodump was initially made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a long research it seems that the process is related to the way that mongodump was initially made

to clarify even further:

to dump a tar :

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<IP_OF_YOUR_MONGO>:27017/<DB_TO_BE_DUMPED>" --gzip --archive=<DUMP_NAME>.tar.gz
```

after the dump was created , it can be restored with :

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<IP_OF_THE_MONGO_TO_BE_RESTORED_TO>:27017/<THE_NEW_DB_TO_BE>" --nsFrom "<THE_DB_THAT_WAS_DUMPED>" --nsTo "<THE_NEW_DB_TO_BE>" --gzip  --archive="<DUMP_NAME>.tar.gz"
```

Comment: Does it also work without database name, e.g. `mongorestore --uri="mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<IP_OF_THE_MONGO_TO_BE_RESTORED_TO>:27017/" --nsFrom ...`?

Comment: its does work when restoring to sama database. but not new database.

Answer (score 0):

So far I only able to restore gzip backup to the same database. To restore to the new database, i dump to directory:

```
mongodump --uri="mongo_url_here" -d dbname -o /backups/dbname_`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`
```

Then rename the folder to new database

```
mv /backups/dbname_`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`/dbname /backups/dbname_`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`/newDbName
```

finally use mongorestore to upload the database to new database

```
mongorestore --uri="mongo_url_here" --nsInclude "newDbName.*" --drop /backups/dbname_`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`
```

Hope this helps =)